# 60s–70s SF novel with time-traveling monsters/demons

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, teleportation, demons

I'm thinking I read this at about age 10, which was in 1970. There was some kind of war being fought across time between humans and ferocious monsters (or demons?). They were colorful (red-skinned) and capable of teleportation. The humans had ornithopter-type aircraft. I'm sketchy on the details (I was 10), but the writing style reminds me of Doc Savage.

Comment: Could be mis-remembered [Galaxy Primes](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/20898/pg20898-images.html) by E.E Smith?

Comment: No, this involved ?demons?, a lot of time-shifting, I believe it didn't leave Earth.